# How to migrate from working input range to elm-mdl Slider?

Tags: elm, elm-mdl

I currently have a function that I use for a range, and number input type for each piece of data (trait). Updates to the model are done via `EditTrait Mhid Relevance` message.

```
valueRange : String -> TraitWithRelevance -> Html Msg
valueRange typ trait =
    let
        ( name, mhid, relevance ) =
            trait
    in
        input [ Attr.type_ typ, Attr.min "0", Attr.max "100", Attr.value relevance, Attr.step "1", onInput <| EditTrait mhid ] []
```

In an attempt to bring in Google's material design through elm-mdl, I want to replace the `valueRange "range"` call with the `valueSlider` function which utilizes the Slider component from elm-mdl.

[image: rendered slider]

The code below compiles, but obviously doesn't work, because the important onChange handler is missing. However, it renders correctly and the slider changes, when I update a trait's relevance value through the input number element.

```
valueSlider trait =
    let
        ( name, mhid, relevance ) =
            trait

        relAsFloat =
            String.toFloat relevance |> Result.toMaybe |> Maybe.withDefault 0
    in
        Slider.view
            [ Slider.value relAsFloat
            , Slider.min 0
            , Slider.max 100
            , Slider.step 1
            ]
```

When I throw in `Slider.onChange (EditTrait mhid)`, which works on the regular input, the compiler gives me this error.

> The argument to function `onChange` is causing a mismatch.
>
> 438|               Slider.onChange (EditTrait mhid)
>                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Function `onChange` is expecting the argument to be:
>
> ```
> Float -> m
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> Relevance -> Msg
> ```
>
> Detected errors in 1 module.

Comment: Can you provide the definition for `Relevance` and `EditTrait`?

Answer (score 1):

As `onInput` type is `(String -> msg) -> Html.Attribute msg` I suppose `Relevance` is a `String`, and `EditTrait` is `mhid -> String -> Msg`.

In this case, `Slider.onChange (EditTrait mhid)` doesn't work because `Slider.onChange` expects a `Float -> Msg` not `Relevance -> Msg` (as the compiler message reads.)

To solve this issue, you should change `EditTrait` to receive a `Float` instead of `String`. Changing `Relevance` type to be a `Float` and updating the code accordingly should do the trick.